# Tracking which random swf loads

Tags: php, javascript, html

The following code loads 3 swf files randomly 1 at a time in the same div.
How can i track which swf loads at a particular time in PHP or javascript b'se i want to use IF statements somewhere like if($i==1) where $i is a variable equal to one when 1.swf loads & $i==2 when 2.swf loads.

```
            function loadFlash(){

                function getRandomFilename()
                {
                    var names = [
                        '1.swf', 
                        '2.swf',
                        '3.swf'
                    ];
                    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
                    return names[r];
                }

                var flashvars = {};
                var params = {wmode:"opaque"};
                var attributes = {};
                swfobject.embedSWF(getRandomFilename(), "SWF_Output", "900", "120", "8.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);

            }
```

Mob ... Thanks in advance

Comment: Cool, got it. names[r]; variable stores the path of the swf being loaded at any given time

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code like this:

```
function loadFlash(){
    function getRandomFilename() {
        var names = [
            '1.swf', 
            '2.swf',
            '3.swf'
        ];
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
        return [names[r], r];
    }

    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {wmode:"opaque"};
    var attributes = {};
    var file = getRandomFilename();
    swfobject.embedSWF(file[0], "SWF_Output", "900", "120", "8.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
    //file[0] will be the file name   ('1.swf' - '3.swf')
    //file[1] will be the array index (0 - 2)
}
```

You won't be able to access `names[r]` outside of the `getRandomFilename` function ([out of scope](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/))

Comment: Thx Cerbrus, tht makes life easier.